# Updating content on ASP.NET website with C# Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services

I'm going to be building a website using ASP.NET and C# that will be a basic Announcements board.  The people who will be updating the content would like a standalone application to easily add and delete announcements on the site.  I'm new to web programming and am looking for recommendations on how to best go about this.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. If you can, perhaps use SharePoint Foundation. It's free, and it does everything you need it to do, plus much, much more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ASP.Net](http://www.asp.net) website is full of information.  You might want to check out [WebMatrix](http://www.asp.net/web-pages), which is free and a very good tool that is more approachable to new programmers.